# How do I bind a mouse button (specifically the scroll wheel buttons `4` and `5`) to a keyboard key on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, key-binding, i3-window-manager

The scroll wheel on my mouse is broken (though middle-click still works, apparently) and I would like to bind two of my keyboard keys (yes, I have spare keys for this) in such a way as to emulate <kbd>mouse scroll up</kbd> and <kbd>mouse scroll down</kbd> by sending the requisite actions to X. How do I go about doing this? The keycodes I intend to use are `f13` and `f18` (for the <kbd>F13</kbd> and <kbd>F18</kbd> keys), respectively. I'm using `i3` as my window manager.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I installed the `xdotools` package and added the following to my `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
bindsym F13 xdotools click 4
bindsym F18 xdotools click 5
```